# Replacing parameters in loop with values from a csv

Tags: bash, csv

I am trying to write a bash for loop that execute a python script multiple times, such that it's like this

```
for i from 1 to 10 do 
    arg1 = 'path/to/directory1'
    arg2 = 'path/to/directory2'
    script.py arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 
    done
```

`arg1` and `arg2` are easy because they are static paths that remain consistent over time. However, `arg3` and `arg4` are values that I get from a csv I have and I want arg3 and arg4 to change at each iteration based on the row they are on.

So for a csv like this

```
400 Steve
401 Jack
402 John
403 Jim
404 Jane
405 Joe 
406 Bob
407 Richard
408 Eric 
409 Tim
410 Marie
```

So the first iteration of the loop would be like this

```
script.py path/to/directory1 path/to/directory2 400 Steve
```

Comment: Do you specifically want to stop after 10 iterations, or to continue until the end of the CSV file?

Comment: I'd like to continue to the end of the csv file.I was just throwing in th 10 in there as a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

To read and process all lines from the CSV file, you can use a `while` loop:

```
arg1='path/to/directory1'
arg2='path/to/directory2'

while IFS=, read -r arg3 arg4; do
    script.py "$arg1" "$arg2" "$arg3" "$arg4" 
done < file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(echo "column1,column2"; cat file.csv) | 
csv-exec -- script.py path/to/directory1 path/to/directory2 %column1 %column2
```

csv-exec is from https://github.com/mslusarz/csv-nix-tools